# Re-casting c# variables with a different class

Tags: c#, .net, class

I am new to OOP (especially c#) and was wondering if it is possible to recast object variables to a different class.  My example code is below:

```
public class Student
{
   int id;
   string surname;
   string forename;
}

public class StudentExtra
{
   int id;
   int studentId;
   int ethnicityCode;
}

private void Main()
{
   populateClass("student");
   populateClass("studentextra");
}

private void populateClass(string className)
{
   var useClass;

   switch (className)
   {
      case "student":
         useClass = new Student();
         useClass.Id = 12345;
         useClass.surname = "Nicholls";
         useClass.forename = "Anthony";
         break;

      case "studentextra":
         useClass = new StudentExtra();
         useClass.Id = 121212;
         useClass.StudentID = 12345;
         useClass.EthnicityCode = 10;
      break;
   }
}
```

The reason for doing it this way, is that I was hoping to re-use the same populateClass method (as I have several classes to process) and the class variable so that the appropriate class can be populated with data coming in from a deserialized JSON string.  Is this possible?

Thanks
Anthony

--- Additional information ---
the following works for the student class, but I would then need to create a method for
each of the classes involved (over 60 all with different properties as you would expect).

```
Student useClass;

string r = "";

using (WebResponse res = req.GetResponse())
{
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
   {
      r = sr.ReadToEnd();                        
   }
}

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
useClass = js.Deserialize<student>(r);
```

If the only way is to create those methods, then that is what I will do.

Comment: Are you asking about inheritance? You want the StudentExtra class to be a child of the Student class?

Comment: Should `StudentExtra` not extend `Student`?

Comment: `var useClass;` won't compile.

Comment: Depends exactly what you are trying to do here. Inheritance or interfaces would be a good start. But also if you're loading form JSON, perhaps you need to look at JSON.Net and `TypeNameHandling`

Comment: `var userclass` , no type, so won't compile … it should rather be `Classname userClass`

Comment: Thanks Anthony for responding.  No, the classes are all totally independent of each other (they come from a SQL table that is outside my control).  I can only read/write data through API.  The student extra was probably a bad example as it would automatically be suggested for extending the class.

Comment: Why does "populateClass" have multiple different responsibilities? Surely you want `populateStudentClass()` and `populateStudentExtraClass()`?

Comment: When your classes are completeley unrelated, why even have instances of different classes in the same variable?

Comment: @john , I don't think it matters...

Comment: @zackraiyan It matters a lot

Comment: Show us your JSON and we can probably simplify this whole thing.

Comment: @PatrickHofman , if you are talking about these lines :`populateClass("student");
   populateClass("studentextra");` then please explain how it matters ?

Comment: @AnthonyNicholls So to clarify, you are accepting a JSON file populated by a database and are trying to loop through each of those objects and create separate classes based upon a value specified inside of that object?

Comment: "re-use the same populateClass method" Well, I can´t see much you can really re-use except the single `var useClass` (which doesn´t even compile). So this attemp is pretty useless, make two methods.

Comment: @zack Because student and studentextra are completely unrelated objects. Reading the code it's unclear what the method does because it has multiple unrelated responsibilities. Why not `populateClass("UIButton")` and `populateClass("DbContext")`? Using magic strings is also typically bad practice. If it's going to be generating objects of different types, that means that you will have to return `object`, so you lose the type safety and will have to cast the result. If you cast the result to the wrong type, you introduce runtime errors.

Comment: @AnthonyNicholls , dude, this is why don't ever post pusedo codes here, atleast not the wrong one :(

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to write several versions of the same populateClass method to deal with the different classes.

Comment: @Anthony but if the source data is JSON, what does `populateClass` actually do? Doesn't the serializer take care of that for you?

Comment: If the classes are completely separate and you don't want any type of inheritance on them, you should make separate methods for each class.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to write several versions of the same populateClass method to deal with the different classes.

So the two independent JSON responses are:

    {
      "Surname": "Nicholls",
      "Forename": Anthony,
      "Id": 12345
    }



    {
      "StudentID": 12345
      "EthncityCode": 10,
      "Id": 121212
    }


Once inserted into their appropriate class via the populateClass method, I would then retrieve the ID from the class and generate a new JSON string for inserting into another system via an API call.

Comment: Can you show us how you deserialize your JSON?

Comment: @john, I have added the JSON deserialization in the question above.

Comment: @Anthony I'm not sure what you're trying to avoid duplicating, but I've added an example that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you refactor it so that you have a generic method that takes a `WebResponse`?

```
public T Deserialize<T>(WebResponse response)
    where T: new() // ensure that any type of T used has a parameterless constructor
{
    string r = "";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        r = sr.ReadToEnd();                        
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return js.Deserialize<T>(r);
}
```

Usage:

```
var student= Deserialize<student>(res);
```